# Carriage return doesn't work as expected in PowerShell ISE

Tags: shell, powershell, carriage-return, powershell-ise

I have this command:

```
Write-Host "123`r456"
```

Output in stand-alone PowerShell:

```
456
```

Output in PowerShell ISE:

```
123456
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ISE doesn't behave like a normal console in many ways. While you would expect the carriage return to reset the position to the first character of a line, and hence give the outout `456`, the ISE does not work that way, so do not depend on that behaviour.

This is one of the undocumented differences of ISE from the normal console. Documented ones are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/04/17/differences-between-the-ise-and-powershell-console.aspx